# MPI:  пример простой программы

Tags: mpi

Только начинаю работать с `MPI`.
Первый пример программы не правильно работает..

```
 #include <mpi.h>
 int main (int argc, char* argv[])
 {
   char message [20];
   int myrank;
   MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
   if (myrank==0)
   {
     strncpy(message,”Hello, there!\0”,15);
     MPI_Send (message, strlen(message)+1, MPI_CHAR, 1,99,
     MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   }
   else
   {
     MPI_Recv (message, 20, MPI_CHAR, 0,99,
     MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
     printf (“received: %s \n”, message);
   }
   MPI_Finalize();
   return 0;
 }
```

Компилирую

```
mpicc -o 1 1.c
```

Запускаю

```
mpirun -np 2 ./1
```

Не работает ( Появляется ошибка, связанная с `MPI_Send`..
Может кто-нибудь работает с `MPI`? Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так..

Ошибка такая

```
MPI_Send(173): MPI_Send(buf=0x7fff61738e48, count=1, MPI_INT, dest=3, tag=15,    MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPI_Send(98).: Invalid rank has value 1 but must be nonnegative and less than 1
```

Comment: Судя по коду, у Вас ошибка при пересылке: рут посылает буфер длиной 6 символов, а слейв принимает буфер на 20 символов. А судя по тексту ошибки, у Вас в MPI-процессе участвует только одна нода, которая пытается послать что-то второй (которой не существует).  
 --  
Попробуйте проверять, что `MPI_Comm_size > 1`.

Comment: проверила что MPI_Comm_size, ничего хорошего (((


     MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
     printf ("Size = ", size);
     anna@ubuntu:~$ mpiexec -np 2 ./1mp
     Size = Fatal error in MPI_Send: Invalid rank, error stack:
     MPI_Send(173): MPI_Send(buf=0x7fffaa886bc0, count=20, MPI_CHAR, dest=1, tag=99, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
     MPI_Send(98).: Invalid rank has value 1 but must be nonnegative and less than 1

Comment: исправьте:

    printf( "Size = %i\r\n", size );

Comment: исправила, но..(


    anna@ubuntu:~$ mpirun -np 2 ./1mp
    Size = 1 
    Size = 1 
    Fatal error in MPI_Send: Invalid rank, error stack:
    MPI_Send(173): MPI_Send(buf=0x7fffcd8d6930, count=14, MPI_CHAR, dest=1, tag=99, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
    MPI_Send(98).: Invalid rank has value 1 but must be nonnegative and less than 1
    Fatal error in MPI_Send: Invalid rank, error stack:
    MPI_Send(173): MPI_Send(buf=0x7fff7041fb20, count=14, MPI_CHAR, dest=1, tag=99, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
    MPI_Send(98).: Invalid rank has value 1 but must be nonnegative and less than 1

Comment: >mpirun -np 2

---

>Size = 1

Значит что-то не так либо с самим запуском `MPI-процесса`, либо с установкой `MPI`. Это что за реализация? Есть ли в системе какой-то планировщик `MPI`, который контролирует параллельные ресурсы? В сети я иногда еще встречаю такие проблемы, которые решаются переустановкой пакета `MPI`.

Comment: устанавливала так


    sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin openmpi-doc libopenmpi-dev

Comment: Переустановить?

    sudo apt-get --reinstall install openmpi-bin openmpi-doc libopenmpi-dev  
 --  
Моя вот такая минимальная программа печатает ожидаемый вывод для двух процессов:

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <mpi.h>
 
 int main( int argc, char*argv[] ){
   int rank, size;
   //
   MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
   MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank );
   MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size );
   printf( "rank = %i, size = %i\r\n", rank, size );
   MPI_Finalize();
   return 0;
 }

---

    mpicc test.c
    mpiexec -np 2 ./a.out

---

    rank = 0, size = 2
    rank = 1, size = 2